# sorting a vector according to some attribute in it

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, stdvector

If I have the following vector:

```
vector< pair < pair< char,int >,pair< int,int > > >
```

How can I sort  in descending order using `<algorithm>` library according to the integer part in the first pair? 
(I want to use `sort(vector.begin() , vector.end() )`

Comment: "I have the following vector: `vector< pair< char,int >,pair< int,int > >`" No you don't. That's not a valid type. Show your actual declaration.

Comment: `vector <pair<pair<char,int>,pair<int,int> > > buy; `


this exactly my declaration

Comment: oh, add one more `pair` in your question :)

Comment: I already did .. I wonder if someone can help :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548505/equivalent-of-pythons-list-sort-with-key-schwartzian-transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using MyVector = vector< pair < pair< char,int >,pair< int,int > > >;
MyVector v;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const MyVector::value_type& a, const MyVector::value_type& b) {
      return a.first.second > b.first.second;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), 
    []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 ) { return p1.first.second > p2.first.second; } );
```

If your compiler does not support auto in `lambda` expressions then you have to specify the type of the vector elements explicitly for example using a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122804/how-to-sort-with-a-lambda) as a reference:

> ```
> sort(mMyClassVector.begin(), mMyClassVector.end(), 
>     [](const MyClass & a, const MyClass & b) -> bool
> { 
>     return a.mProperty > b.mProperty; 
> });
> ```

Use lambda and define what should be '>' when you get two objects from your vector.

Comment: Please add to your answer the relevant pieces from that link. Link-only answers will get deleted. Links get stale over time.

Comment: @chr No problem. I've just added it.