# Sorting a buffer of data packets with specific structure

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++, buffer, pcm

I need to sort data packets which have been transmitted over a TCP server/network in ASCENDING order based on the SEQ number (which is just an unsigned 4 byte integer). In other words, I want to rearrange my data buffer (I am using std::vector for simplicity), so that the data is ordered in ASCENDING order by SEQ, followed by the respective CHECKSUM and LEN (length/size in bytes) of the packet, as well as the actual (byte) data of course...

Each data packet follows the structure outlined below, and there will be duplicate SEQ numbers (I shouldn't have too much difficulty verifying the good data packets using a CHECKSUM mechanism once I have the data in order).

[image]

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated, and I do apologize in advance, if this has been previously answered.

Comment: To simplified your question, is it "I want to sort a bunches of item by its SEQ"? Seems most of information is describing data itself but non are describing sorting. You may show what you have tried, or i'll suggest using [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122804/how-to-sort-with-a-lambda).

Comment: The lambda (or any comparator) is what I though of as well, however how would I reorder "LEN" bytes following the 12th byte (as well as the 0th-12th bytes in the header)...I mean with a lambda I am just returning the lesser of 2 sequences...but how is that going to inform the sorting to move ALL of the bytes associated with that SEQ? Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. I don't get why sorting by SEQ would affect LEN order. If each packet has one LEN and corresponding bytes, then it should be an independent work for rearranging data inside of a packet.

Comment: It would not affect LEN order (I am not trying to reorder the data inside each packet), but I am trying to sort my entire data buffer (effectively stitch) the packets to go by ASC SEQ order...the problem is moving all of a SEQ's associated bytes around...

Comment: Okay..are all packets lying in a raw buffer array not without a simple struct? Because you mentioned `std::vector`, I assumes you already put each packet in a struct, but I might be wrong. Is putting each packet into a stand along POD not allowed in your case?

Comment: The packets are all placed in a std::vector<byte> (I did not put each packet in a struct), so there is no other way to differentiate between when one starts and ends except for using the 4 bytes in LEN (which is part of our header) to determine that. Now that I think about it, you are probably right in that I should have each data packet as a struct, or maybe try using a map< SEQ (uint32_t), std::vector<std::vector<byte>> >...that way it inserts in correct order? I'll have to think about this a bit more. Hopefully I'll get back to you with something by tomorrow. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You might in the right track atm. However I don't suggest vector of vector for maintainability. A vector of packet is straightforward than guess what a vector of byte is. A vector of byte means ANYthing and nothing.

Comment: Yes, I am now much more in favor of utilizing a struct (maybe call it Packet)...and then having a std::vector<Packet>. That should make a lot more sense...sorting would also be trivial then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your question. A `vector<byte>` represents your buffer

Following are pseudo code for explanation.

```
vector<byte> buffer;
// receive data;

// packet as a struct    
vector<packet> packets = extract_packet( &buffer );

sort(packets .begin(), packets .end(), 
[](const packets & a, const packets & b) -> bool
{ 
    return a.SEQ < b.SEQ; 
});
```

Comment: Yup. That’s what I’ll be trying out tomorrow. I’ll let you know if it works.

Comment: Hey, sorry to take so long. That being said, this worked perfectly fine for me. The output of the PCM data in Audacity isnt very clear but that might just be a data problem. Thanks for all the ideas/help!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to actually sort the buffers themselves, not the data.

To do this, place every raw packet buffer into a list or a map, indexing them by sequence number. Once all packets have been received, walk the list/map from beginning to end and copy the data into a buffer large enough to contain all data, in order.

Comment: Should the first line be "sort the data themselves, not the buffer"? I assume data means packets.

Comment: No, a buffer contains a raw packet from the underlying transport medium. The data is the packet payload. Sort the individual buffers received by the application and coalesce the data after sorting, rather than trying to sort the data via insertion of bytes into arbitrary indices.