# sorting std::vector<std::string> with numeric data

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have a `vector<string>` container but the strings are all numbers

**EDIT**: I tried this:

so now the logic seems to be borked

cleaned this up but experimenting with various attempts to cast std::string to an int is tough
lamba was useless and I have run out of ideas for casting std::string without some bug surfacing

```
template<typename Iterator>void bubbleSort(Iterator first, Iterator last){
    Iterator i, j;
    for (i = first; i != last; i++)
        for (j = first; j < i; j++)
            if (*i < *j)
                std::iter_swap(i, j); // or std::swap(*i, *j);
}
```

My code to read the source data is

```
void loadgames(void) { // read the game app id's
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
string s;
inFile.open("game-list.txt");
if (inFile.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(inFile, s)) {
        if(s.length() > 0)
            gamelist.push_back(s); 
    };
    inFile.close();
}
//  bubbleSort(gamelist.begin(),gamelist.end());
outFile.open("game-list.txt");
if (outFile.is_open()) {
    for (i = gamelist.begin(); i != gamelist.end(); i++) {
        outFile << *i << endl;
    }
}
outFile.close();
```

}

The call to is the problem of sorting my vector

```
bubbleSort(gamelist.begin(),gamelist.end());
```

Comment: *do i need to use a custom function to compare? using std::sort* ? Yes, but it would be a fairly trivial function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort with a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122804/how-to-sort-with-a-lambda)

Comment: "*but the strings are all numbers*" - then why not use `std::vector<int>` instead, and simply parse the strings with `std::stoi()` or equivalent when you are inserting them into the `vector`?

Comment: the data comes from notepad as text so to sort as numeric makes more sense to me, a lambda is one approach but I am struggling with problems in visual studio 2022

Comment: @HardcoreGames "*the data comes from notepad as text*" - so what? You are responsible for inserting the data into your `vector`, so you can transform it however you want to make things easier on yourself. "*I am struggling with problems*" - such as? That would be useful information that you should add as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: The nasty part is which goes first: 1 or 10? With a number, the ordering is obvious. As a string you might be surprised.

Comment: How many elements are there in this `vector`? As @RemyLebeau suggested, it may be better to use a `vector<int>` instead, even if only temporarilly ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/3YTjcKW13)) - also, you should compare `std::string`s in your comparator - not `vector<string>`s - read the answer you've gotten carefully.

Comment: There potentially could be 10,000 elements, the project is 64-bit so I am not worried

Comment: @HardcoreGames Please don't keep changing the question, adding code that you got from the answer. That makes this Q&A really hard to get help from in the future. I suggest you revert your changes where you've copied code from the answer - at least the latest edit. If something is borked, it's not in the code we now see in the question. Note: If the conversion from `string` to `int` fails, `stoi` throws an exception. Have you verified that the data in the `vector<string>` is correct?

Comment: sorry I am still puzzled so I was posting updates

Comment: @HardcoreGames You can ADD new information to your question, but please don't CHANGE past information, it invalidates prior comments/answers and makes it difficult to follow the conversation.

Comment: I have removed useless code and replaced it with functioning code pieces

Comment: @HardcoreGames and in doing so, you have INVALIDATED prior comments/answers AGAIN!  We warned you NOT to do that! Please roll back your recent edits, and then APPEND the new details, DO NOT replace the original content!

Answer (score 6):

As you already know, you can use `std::sort()` with a custom comparator.  The problem is your `compare` is setup wrong.  Its parameters need to be the container's `value_type`, not the container type.  And you have an erroneous `.` in it.

Try this instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> gamelist;
// fill gamelist as needed...

auto compare = [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b){
    return std::stoi(a) < std::stoi(b);
};

std::sort(gamelist.begin(), gamelist.end(), compare);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Dt81cn)

However, I would suggest using `std::vector<int>` instead (or appropriate integer type, depending on your string contents), and simply parse the `std::string`s into integers with `std::stoi()` (or equivalent) before inserting them into the `std::vector`, eg:

```
std::vector<int> gamelist;
// fill gamelist as needed...
gamelist.push_back(std::stoi(someString));
...
std::sort(gamelist.begin(), gamelist.end());
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Ebez39)

This will consume less memory and sort much faster, and it will reduce the complexity of the sort since you will be incurring the overhead of converting strings to integers only one time up front, not on every iteration of the sort algorithm (potentially parsing the same strings over and over).

Comment: after sorting I was intending to write the text file back as notepad friendly text

Comment: I have already written a lot of code based on the std::string but I simply wanted to sort the list as (int)

Comment: Nothing stops you from converting a vector of strings into a vector of ints before sorting, and then converting back afterwards.  But whatever.  My answer already shows you how to sort a vector of strings

Comment: @HardcoreGames `std::sort` needs `O(nlogn)` comaparisons and the proposed solution transforms the strings for every single comparison. I would not be surprised if  transforming to a `std::vector<int>`, sorting, then transforming it back, is less expensive, because it only needs `O(n)` transformations

Comment: sort(gamelist.begin(), gamelist.end()[](const string& a, const string& b) bool{ return (int)a < (int)b;) }
does not seem to be working right?

Comment: @HardcoreGames You can't type-cast a `string` to an `int` like that, you must use a conversion function instead, like `std::stoi()`, as shown in my answer. Also, your syntax is wrong, as it is missing a comma after `end()`, a `->` before `bool`, and the `}` is in the wrong place.

Comment: For some reason the code abends when I call sort. Not sure what is up outside of a VS bug or 50.

Comment: @HardcoreGames "*the code abends when I call sort*" - meaning what, exactly?

Comment: sort with the basic iterators works but adding the custom auto causes it to fail, converted bubble sort to iterators so now this works like sts::sort

Comment: @HardcoreGames "*but adding the custom auto causes it to fail*" - what do you mean by "custom auto"? What kind of failure exactly?  BE SPECIFIC!

Comment: there seems to be problems with atoi()

Comment: @HardcoreGames `atoi()` works just fine (but you should use `stoi()` instead). So the problem has to be with your strings. But since you haven't provided a [mcve], it is hard to troubleshoot exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I have tried all manor of things to cast the string to an int for comparison in the short, even c_str() caused problems with stoi/atio so I am wondering if I need to use &*i and &*j for my iterators to get the sort values

Comment: I abandoned the lambda in favor of the template which I hope to be able to massage into functionality but its brutal to get it working

Comment: @HardcoreGames The problem is not with `stoi`/`atoi` itself, or lambda vs template. It is clear that your strings likely *do not* contain what you are expecting, so you need to debug and fix them from the beginning. Again, if you would provide a [mcve] AND the data you are actually working with, someone is more likely to help you with that.

Comment: values are one number per line that comes from a PHP interface to a database, typical values with 40, 350, 1345, 7623 and so on up to maybe 1850020

Comment: @HardcoreGames That doesn't explain what the database looks like, or how the numbers are getting into your strings. What part of [mcve] is unclear to you?

Comment: I appended the read function ^

Comment: @HardcoreGames You didn't show the ACTUAL contents of `game-list.txt`. Also see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) So it is likely you are pushing an invalid string into your `gamelist` after the file is done being read.

Comment: in my code i check that the input file is opened fine when the while looks checks for the end of the text so there are two conditions being checked

Comment: @HardcoreGames Your `while` loop is simply wrong (did you bother to read [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) I provided?) so there may be 1 final call to `getline()` that will return a blank string, which you push unconditionally into your `gamelist`, which can then break your `atoi`/`stoi` handling. The loop MUST be changed to `while (std::getline(inFile, s)) { gamelist.push_back(s); }` to operate *properly* (assuming there are no blank lines in the file)

Comment: I have added another conditional to check for an empty string, the syntax is correct

Comment: I use !eof which you may have missed

Comment: @HardcoreGames I didn't miss it.  USING `while(!eof)` IS WRONG TO USE where there hasn't been a prior I/O read to update the EOF state.  You clearly do not understand how `eof()` actually works.  It is only valid **after** an I/O read, not **before**, as you were originally treating it.  But whatever.  I'm getting tired of this conversation, you are just dragging this out longer than it needs to be.  I'm done.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and it seems to have solved the sort issues